# Resizing iFrames based on its contents' height only working to enlarge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Take a look at the attached codepen to see what I mean. Try reducing the width of your browser, the frame should correctly resize. Then maximize your browser window and note that the frame doesn't re-adjust its height.

I have multiple frames stacked ontop of each other so this is quite an annoying issue.

I've tried using .height(), .outerHeight(), .innerHeight(), .scrollHeight and .clientHeight to no avail.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxaLPW

```
var newHeight = $('#frame').contents().height();  
$('#frame').attr('height', newHeight);
```

Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Comment: It's a super annoying problem. We've used this library in the past to get around it; https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer - you need access to the parent and child pages though. It does work quite well though, even via cross origin if correctly configured. I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function resizeFrame() {
  var newHeight = $('#frame').contents().find("body").height();
  $('#frame').attr('height', newHeight + 20);
}
```

Comment: Yes that should work - but unfortunately I can't rely on there being a body element in markup that the frames will be displaying.

Comment: So let's say it should work, but it doesn't -  https://codepen.io/chavag/pen/YxypOQ

Comment: you did not add `newHeight + 20` so there will be scroll

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function($){
      var lastHeight = 0, curHeight = 0, $frame = $('iframe:eq(0)');
      setInterval(function(){
        curHeight = $frame.contents().find('body').height();
        if ( curHeight != lastHeight ) {
          $frame.css('height', (lastHeight = curHeight) + 'px' );
          $frame.css('border-width', 0 + 'px' );
        }
      },0);
    });
});
```